# Deleting a binary Java Files

Tags: java

I am trying to find a way to delete the binary files that I have created. I can do it by going to the folder, but I want to do it through the program.

Such as the program asks --> Enter the name of the file you want to delete:
for example: Bob
(processing...)
binary file has been deleted. 
this is what I want my method to do. 
However I do not know how to do it, Is there a method to delete a binary file or do I have to write my own code to delete a binary file?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`File.delete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29), from the linked Javadoc,

> Deletes the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname. If this pathname denotes a directory, then the directory must be empty in order to be deleted.

So I believe you might use something like

```
new File("c:/some/folder/binary.file").delete();
```

Alternatively, you can schedule things to be deleted on exit with [`File.deleteOnExit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()) which

> Requests that the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname be deleted when the virtual machine terminates.

Comment: Also, the `delete()` function returns a boolean value that tells whether or not the deletion succeeded or not.